# Beautiful Soup findAll doesn't find all information

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to parse an HTML page using the BeautifulSoup Python library. However, I am unable to retrieve nested divs/classes beyond a certain point. When using the "findAll" function it does not return all of these tags. This particular site is using Bootstrap, and the info I am looking to retrieve is within an Accordion component. Does BeautifulSoup conflict with Bootstrap or am I not parsing the site correctly?

I am trying to get store location, such as address, postal code.
https://www.needs.ca/en/store-locator/

code i used:

```
req = Request('https://www.needs.ca/en/store-locator/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
web_byte = urlopen(req).read()
with requests.Session() as c:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(web_byte,'lxml')
soup
```

Can any web scrapping masters shed some light here? Really appreciated

Comment: standard problem which you can see in many questions: this page uses JavaScript to add elements but `urllib`, `requests`, `BeautifulSoup`,`lxml` can't run JavaScript. You may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the network tab in the developer tools to get the API endpoints. On a quick look, POST `https://www.needs.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` is the endpoint they use. It returns JSON that looks like this:

```json
{
  page: 1,
  total_page: 26,
  is_default: false,
  stores: [],
}
```

"Here's the python code you need to get it. I've tested the code so it should work."

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:98.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/98.0",
    "Host": "www.needs.ca"
}
data = {"action":"search_nearest_stores","lng":"-0.1234","lat":"79.3453","page":"1"}

def main():
    res = requests.post("https://www.needs.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", headers=headers, data=data)
    if res.status_code == 200:
        print(res.text)
    else:
        print(res.status_code, res.reason)

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I tried this before, it gives 403 error code.

Comment: @RogerWang You need to first make a request to `https://www.needs.ca/en/store-locator/` to get the headers, then make a request to `https://www.needs.ca/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`.

Comment: Can you provide some code? I will be really appreciated. i looked at other people's code, but only able to retrieve <html><head></head><body>0</body></html> from that url. I am a newbie to Web Scraping.

Comment: @RogerWang I've updated the code. It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! Web Scraping Master. It works!!! You made my day. May i know how do you find """action:search_nearest_stores""" you specify under data?

Comment: @RogerWang in the network tab, after clicking the request you can see the request data that was sent. If my answer was useful, please upvotes my answer, and mark it as the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i will. I am super new to this community, I need to get 15 reputation to upvote. But I will come back to upvote for sure since you are the first one help me solve a problem in this community